# Lowest API level used for Android development as of November-2015

Tags: android, api, sdk

I am developing new application. I just want to know that what would be the lowest API version that should be used for my application ? Currently I am using minimum API level-14 (Ice Cream Sandwich) and targeting API is Level-23 (Marshmallow).

I have followed http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#OpenGL for the same. Any other things that should be taken care to choose minimum API level.

Comment: i think API level 8 is also used as min sdk version in many projects... though many classes not works below 14 but usualy 8 is still working

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't do any search.

Comment: Here's the info you need: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I have done research on API level and I was confused so i want some opinion from the experts.

Comment: It's not about **opinions**. The dashboard tells you **clearly**.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I want to know other things that should be taken care that is the only reason to ask this question

Comment: The answer you accepted is taken from the dashboard.

Comment: All you needed to know is in the dashboard. But you still need to learn **searching**, before asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

so as of today only 4% of devices are using API level lower than 15

So keeping minimum SDK as 15 you will be able to cover a decent amount of users with less hassle for managing compatibility on lower SDK versions.

[this page](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) will give you a head start for other factors to consider while targeting your apps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I made a correction in my answer it's 4% and not 18%

Answer (score 0):

I'am reworking an old app and i'am using API 14 as the minimum. 
If you are using Android Studio and create a new project it gives you some numbers on how many devices you will support:
[image: API 14 percentages]

So with API 14 you support ~94% of the devices that are active on the Play Store.